# jQuery mouse event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent

I have following code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="one">Content</div>
<div class="two">Content</div>
```

I want to hide my second `div` when `mosueleave` event happen from first `div` and also the mouse don't have over second `div`.

**Algorithm:**

```
if ((mouseleave from div.one) && (mouse not on div.two))
     hide (div.two);
```

How can I implement this snippet using jquery? please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a flag on the `.two` div that keeps track of the mouseover state. Then when the mouse leaves `.one` you check for this state and if it exists you hide the div. Like so:

```
$(".two").live("mouseenter", function(){
    $(this).data("hover", true);
}).live("mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).removeData("hover");
});

$(".one").live("mouseleave", function(){
  if( !$(".two").data("hover") ) $(".two").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

enclose both `div`s in another, say, `div class='zero'`. so you would have something in your `$(document).ready()` like

```
$('.zero').live('hover', function() {
  $('.two').show();
});

$('.zero').live('blur', function() {
  $('.two').hide();
});
```

note: you must `style="display: none"` for `div class='two'` by default

Comment: Hi friend, It is not possible to change the HTML. So give some alternative solution.